# How to give tint color to imageview android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-imageview

I have to change tint color of imageview but programmatically.
I will be getting a string value from server for eg:

> "color":"#fff"

I have to set the same color as tint to an imageview.

The following code will not work =, as the image present in imageview is not set as background of it, but as src.

```
imageView.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#ff8800"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Also, these are following i tried with no luck. :(
Attempt1:

```
ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(imageView, ColorStateList.valueOf(Integer.parseInt("#ffffff")));
```

Attempt2:

```
imageView.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, Color.parseColor("#ffffff")), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Attempt3:

```
imageView.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.______), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Kindly Note, I cannot use R.color.SOMETHING ,as i dont have that color in my file.

Thanking in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
imageView.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
```

The valid color formats for [Color.parseColor()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color#parseColor(java.lang.String)) are

> #RRGGBB and #AARRGGBB

I think you know the following, but I will state it anyway: If the "#fff" value is a CSS hex color code then it is a shortened version of the real code "#FFFFFFFF". If you are passing in just "#fff", it will fail since [Color.parseColor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color#parseColor(java.lang.String)) doesn't know about shortened 3-digit CSS color codes. See [CSS HEX Colors](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_colors_hex.asp).